# Add a custom search engine via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine

I am trying to create a very simple site that uses the [Google Charts QR API](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chld=|0&chs=250&cht=qr&chl=Foo%20Bar) to generate QR codes. The code I'm using is quite simply

```
<form id="QR" action="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart" target="QRwindow" method="POST">
  <h1>QR Code<br/>Generator</h1>
  <textarea autofocus name="chl"
  onkeypress="if(event.which==13&&!event.shiftKey){document.getElementById('cht').click();event.preventDefault();}"
  onkeyup="if(this.value.length&gt;2000) this.value=this.value.substring(0,1500)"></textarea>
  <div>QR size (px):</div>
  <input type="hidden" name="chld" value="|0"/>
  <input type="number" name="chs" value="250" min="50" max="275"/>
  <button type="submit" name="cht" id="cht" value="qr">Generate!</button>
</form>
<iframe name="QRwindow" id="QRwindow" width="275" height="275" frameborder="0" src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chld=|0&chs=250&cht=qr&chl=Foo%20Bar"></iframe>
```

http://jsbin.com/fule/2/

What I'd like to do is add a button that automatically lets the user add the search engine with the following url:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chld=|0&chs=250&cht=qr&chl=%s
```

but I couldn't find any way to automatically add the search engine for the user. I of course understand this could be a security risk, but there's also the possibility to add a handler gmail as for `mailto:`, so I'd imagine a kind-of similar browser setting like adding a search engine to be possible (be it with the user's confirmation) too. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by creating an xml doc with the search engine information, and add it with:

```
window.external.AddSearchProvider('/linktoyourxmldoc.xml')
```

Your XML shall have the following attributes:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
    <ShortName>QR creator</ShortName>
    <Description>Create a QR code.</Description>
    <Tags>qr</Tags>
    <Contact>youremail@email.com</Contact>
    <Url type="text/html" template="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chld=|0&amp;chs=250&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

I have not yet got this to work in chrome.

Edit: 
It wasn't working, you need to change the & signs to `&amp;`.

This is all according to the [opensearch standard](http://www.opensearch.org/Home). More search options and info are on [this](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1) page.

I don't know why it's not working in chrome, as [this](http://www.opensearch.org/Community/OpenSearch_enabled_search_clients) document states that it also works in chrome.

It also [seems](http://blog.coredumped.org/2012/04/opensearch-how-to-get-google-chrome-to.html) that you can directly put a link in your header:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/linktoyourxmldoc.xml" title="MySite Search" />
```

Comment: What browsers do support this? And do you have any reference wiht more information about this?

Comment: [this JSBin works in Chrome](http://jsbin.com/nusa/1/). The problem was probably that your content-type in the script was not `application/opensearchdescription+xml` (which apparently has file extension `.osdx`), but `text/xml`. In Firefox, it says the search engine is not supported, and in IE it returns an error saying `window.external` is undefined, but running the script manually returns an error saying `permission denied`. Finally, Opera just doesn't support it. I didn't test Safari.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Does not seem to work for me in Chrome 46

Comment: @Alex the jsbin seems to be gone for some reason. That link is broken I guess.